# Connection string to SQL Server Express only works from the same server but not from other clients

Tags: c#, sql, dbconnection

I have this connection string and working well when I test my aplication from the same SQL Express, I have an instance called DOKUSTAR.

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"server=.\DOKUSTAR;Database=RdaDB10;Trusted_Connection=Yes"))
using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(@"select top(1) pais, clase, operation from Document_Class where codigoafip = @codafip", conn))
```

The problem is when I tried to connect from outside of the server does not works the connection and show me the following messages:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.(provider: SQL Network interfaces, error:26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified).

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the SQL server configured to allow remote connections? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-remote-access-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: I suppose that you need to use the remote machine name instead of .

Comment: The allow remote connection are already configured. where would be mi error? maybe int the authentication?

Comment: @Steve yes, i was thinking the same but, how can i do that since i have not much  expertice in c#. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Get your app out of the equation.  Try connecting to the SQL instance from a SQL Server Management Studio instance on another machine.  Use the connection string that works from there.

Answer (score 0):

`.\DOKUSTAR` refers to an instance of DOKUSTAR on the current machine.

You need to change it to `MACHINE_NAME\DOKUSTAR`